# RDP Version Number?

Tags: remote-desktop, version

Does any know how to get the RDP version Windows is running with?

Answer (score 12):

Or you could Right click on the window and select About
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Windows RDP uses the executable mstsc.exe located in c:\windows\system32

Simply right click on this file, and go to properties, then click the version tab.

hope this helps.

Comment: I like this answer the best because the exe's property details will tell you the full major.minor.build.revision, where as About just has major.minor.build.  I'm not sure why you might ever need the revision number, but I'm all for the extra info.

Comment: But it doesn't tell you what RDP protocol is supported. For example, mstsc version 6.x supports RDP protocol 7 and 8.1

Answer (score 4):

Here's a PowerShell query you can use:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\windows\\system32\\mstsc.exe" get manufacturer, name, version
```

Answer (score 3):

or you could also click Start > Run > mstsc and when you see the Remote Desktop Connection window appear, click the top left hand corner "computer" icon and select "About".

Answer (score 0):

There can be maybe better way with PowerShell.

First one need complete table of MSTSC build numbers and just compare to output of:

```
(Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

And the second one is to read CLSID of registered components which contain also RDP binaries, like that:

```
$Current = 0
$GUID = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID" | Select Name
$GUIDNum = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID" | Select Name | Measure
While($Current -ne $GUIDNum.Count) {
$Path = $GUID[$Current] | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$GUIDName = ((get-itemproperty -literalpath "Registry::$Path").'(default)') 
If ($GUIDName -like 'Microsoft RDP Client Control (redistributable) - version*')
{
Write-Host $GUIDName
}
$Current++
}
```