# How to get the saved password of a RDP connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, password-recovery

2 Years before one my client given the password for a remote server available in USA, I have directly typed the password in the screen and saved the credential. Now I need to forward the same credential to another person. So is there any way I can know the saved password for that machine.

Comment: This is a link to a very similar topic.  The answers have two links you could try. http://superuser.com/questions/307776/are-saved-remote-desktop-credentials-secure-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Why don't you ask the client?

Comment: @DaveRook: Client changed. New person do not know the password.

Comment: Are you saying the client doesn't have admin access to the USA server?

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought (and hoped) that the password is hashed (i.e. [saved in a non reversible way](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t)).

So, unless you know it (you don't), you will have to ask for a new password from the remote site administrator (I won't even mention a brute force approach which is probably illegal).

Comment: The answer is wrong - passwords, on the client side, won't be stored in a hashed way, because when connecting, you're passing the orginal password to the server, which then hashes it and compares it to a stored hash (usually salted).